# Check the existence of a column in customer eav table

Tags: magento-1.6, model, eav

I write a code to create a sql file to add **a column** to `customer eav table`. I want to check whether that field exist in customer table or not.

here is my code for creating that field >>

```
$setup = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_setup', 'core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'nationalcode', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'national code',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'default' => '',
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 1,
));
```

what should I add to this code to check the existence of the "**nationalcode**" field before creating it?

Comment: Minor note, won't matter in 99.999% of cases: the second argument for this setup class *should* be `customer_setup`.

Comment: tnx, but why is that?

Comment: Your "default" connection info is set in *`app/etc/local.xml`* under the `global/resources/default_setup/connection` XPath, a.k.a. the `default_setup` connection. When EAV resource models are instantiated, they are told which adapters to use (ref `customer_write` in `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer::__construct()`). Internally this gets aliased to the core setup config - which aliased to the default setup config- if not explicitly set; ref `Mage_Core_Model_Resource::getConnection()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are pretty close to the answer already. `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup::addAttribute()` contains a check itself to determine whether the operation is an insert or an update:

```
public function addAttribute($entityTypeId, $code, array $attr)
{
    $entityTypeId = $this->getEntityTypeId($entityTypeId);
    $data = array_merge(
        array(
            'entity_type_id' => $entityTypeId,
            'attribute_code' => $code
        ),
        $this->_prepareValues($attr)
     );

    $this->_validateAttributeData($data);

    $sortOrder = isset($attr['sort_order']) ? $attr['sort_order'] : null;
    $attributeId = $this->getAttribute($entityTypeId, $code, 'attribute_id');
    if ($attributeId) {
        $this->updateAttribute($entityTypeId, $attributeId, $data, null, $sortOrder);
    } else {
        $this->_insertAttribute($data);
    }
    //snip...
}
```

As you can see, your installer class instance (`Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup`) has the necessary method.

```
//Returns associative array if attribute exists, null if not
$installer->getAttribute('customer','nationalcode');
```

That said, you can see the importance of namespacing attribute codes. It's always good to check, but `aamiri_nationalcode` would be a "safer" choice.